# jQuery and PHP login page

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, authentication

So I have made a login handler, but want to call to it from my login page. It doesn't seem to run past the console.log(post_array);, Ive tried using onclick and action, but these do not seem to work. Thank you

```
    <body>
        <div class="login-box">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <br>
            <form name="login">
                <p>Username</p>
                <input id="textbox_username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
                <p>Password</p>
                <input id="textbox_password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="LogUserIn()">
                <a href="#">Forget Password</a>
                <a class="text-right" href="register.php">New Account</a>
            </form>


        </div>

    </body>

    <script>
        function LogUserIn() {
            let username = document.getElementById("textbox_username").textContent;
            let password = document.getElementById("textbox_password").textContent;
            let post_array = {
                'username': username,
                'password': password
            }
            console.log(post_array);

            $.post("http://www.vulkan-apis.xyz/Backend/Users/login.php", post_array, (data) => {
                if (data["success"] == true) {
                    window.location.replace("http://vulkan-apis.xyz/Frontend/index.php");
                } else {
                    console.log("Uh-Oh!");
                }
            }, "json");
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: change Login button to : `<input type="button" value="Login" onclick="LogUserIn()">` or `<button type="button" onclick="LogUserIn()">Login</button>` . And your `LogUserIn` function will executed on click

Answer (score 0):

Please prevent the form from submission. As the button is of type submit, it will submit the form and ignore the onClick function. You can pass an event argument like `<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="LogUserIn(event)">` and then use `event.preventDefault()` in the function.

```js
function LogUserIn(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let username = document.getElementById("textbox_username").value;
    let password = document.getElementById("textbox_password").value;
    let post_array = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
    }
    console.log(post_array);
    //Ajax code ...
}
```

```html
<div class="login-box">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <br>
        <form name="login">
            <p>Username</p>
            <input id="textbox_username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
            <p>Password</p>
            <input id="textbox_password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="LogUserIn(event)">
            <a href="#">Forget Password</a>
            <a class="text-right" href="register.php">New Account</a>
        </form>

    </div>
```

> Please use `value` property like `document.getElementById("textbox_username").value` not `document.getElementById("textbox_username").textContent`

Hope this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you combining ajax and javasript at the same time. You can just do everything straight with jquery. I have updated
your code both jquery, forms and a simulated phpbackend

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('#LogUserIn').click(function(){

var username = $('#textbox_username').val();
var password = $('#textbox_password').val();

        if(username==""){

            alert('please Enter Username');


        }
else if(password==""){

            alert('please Enter Username Password');


        }

else{

        $('#loader').fadeIn(400).html('<br><span class="well"><img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Please Wait,Login In Progress</span>');

var datasend = "username="+ username + "&password=" + password;

        $.ajax({

            type:'POST',
            url:'http://www.vulkan-apis.xyz/Backend/Users/login.php',
            data:datasend,
                        crossDomain: true,
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){

//empty textbox after form submission
                $('#username').val('');
                                $('#password').val('');
//display a loading image during form processing
                $('#loader').hide();

// show success or failed result
                $('#result').fadeIn('slow').prepend(data);



if (data.status == 'success') {
                    window.location.replace("http://vulkan-apis.xyz/Frontend/index.php");
                } 

if (data.status == 'failed') {
                   alert("There is problem with your Username or password");
                }

else {
                    console.log("Uh-Oh!");
                }



            }

        });

        }

    })

});


</script>



<body>
        <div class="login-box">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <br>

                <p>Username</p>
                <input id="textbox_username" type="text" name="textbox_username" placeholder="Enter Username">
                <p>Password</p>
                <input id="textbox_password" type="password" name="textbox_password" placeholder="Enter Password">

<div id="loader"></div>
<div id="result"></div>

                <input type="submit" value="Login" id="LogUserIn">
                <a href="#">Forget Password</a>
                <a class="text-right" href="register.php">New Account</a>



        </div>

    </body>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$output = array();

//lets assume that correct username is nancy and correct password is nancy123

if($username =='nancy' && $password =='nancy123'){
$output[] = array(
"status" => 'success'
);

}
 else{
$output[] = array(
"status" => 'failed'
);

}


echo json_encode($output);
?>
```